# iText - Rendering paragraph at bottom of page with image

Tags: java, itext

I'm working with iText 2.1.7. On the final page of a document that I'm generating I've got a signature paragraph that I always want rendered at the bottom of the last page.

I'm bundling all of my text together into a paragraph and then placing it all in a single cell table and using PDFWriter to write it to a fixed position on the page. The text in the paragraph is showing up fine but the image is not being included.

When I just add the paragraph itself directly to the report the image renders fine but I don't have the positioning control that I need here.

Here's the snippet of code:

```
    private void addSignatureAndContactInformationAndParagraphThree() throws DocumentException {
    Font bold = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, PDFReportUtils.SIGNATURE_NAME_FONT_SIZE);
    Font regular = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, PDFReportUtils.BODY_FONT_SIZE);

    Chunk kindRegards = new Chunk("Kind regards,\n", regular);
    Chunk companyName = new Chunk(getReport().getCompanyName() + "\n", regular);
    Chunk author = new Chunk(getReport().getReportAuthor() + "\n", bold);
    Chunk email = new Chunk(getReport().getReportAuthorEmail() + "\n", regular);
    Chunk phone = new Chunk(getReport().getReportAuthorPhone() + "\n\n", regular);

    PdfPTable singleCellTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    singleCellTable.setTotalWidth((getPdfDocument().right(getPdfDocument().rightMargin())
            - getPdfDocument().left(getPdfDocument().leftMargin())) + 300f);
    PdfPCell singleCell = new PdfPCell();
    singleCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

    Paragraph signatureImageBlock = new Paragraph();
    signatureImageBlock.add(kindRegards);
    if(getSignatureImage() != null)
    {
        signatureImageBlock.add(getSignatureImage());
    }
    signatureImageBlock.add(companyName);
    signatureImageBlock.add(author);
    signatureImageBlock.add(email);
    signatureImageBlock.add(phone);
    signatureImageBlock.add(getParagraphThree());

    singleCell.addElement(signatureImageBlock);
    singleCellTable.addCell(singleCell);

    singleCellTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1,
            getPdfDocument().left(getPdfDocument().leftMargin()) - 45f,
            singleCellTable.getTotalHeight() + getPdfDocument().bottom(getPdfDocument().bottomMargin()),
            writer.getDirectContent());
}
```

The getSignatureImage() checks to see if the user has a signature image configured and then an image from the harddrive (Here's the return statement):

```
return Image.getInstance(signatureImagePath);
```

Any idea why it would render all the text fine but not include the image at all?I've debugged this to ensure that it is getting an image back from getSignatureImage()

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. I needed to add the image to a chunk in order to have it render correctly! Hope this helps someone else.

```
Chunk signatureImage = new Chunk(getSignatureImage(), 0, 0, true);
        signatureImageBlock.add(signatureImage);
```